# How to change the font size of only for one textview in a setting ( listview)?

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, font-size

I am creating a chatting app for a school project and I need to add a list of choices between three different font sizes in the SettingActivity, so you can switch between font sizes whenever you like. It only needs to affect the chat and thus not the whole app.  I am lost from here.

Comment: Its unclear what are you saying and what do you want to achieve and how ? Specially without any screenshot ?

Comment: textview..setTextSize(18);

Answer (score 1):

Save the font size in shared prefrences when user goes to setting activity ,

In the chat listview use an adapter that will check the size prefrences when it initialize the list , than define the textviews in that size using **this:**

```
     holder.textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,YOUR_NEW_SIZE);
```

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

use the following XML files......

```
<com.mobsandgeeks.ui.TypefaceTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    geekui:customTypeface="fonts/custom_font.ttf" />
```